# Report Parameter Value not set error VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, report

I am making a small application in VB to export a report from a server to a PDF. I have tested it with a report without parameters, and it worked fine so I know the URLs and everything are correct. But the parameters are not working, and I have Googled extensively and tried everything. I've tried both an array and a list of parameters (both shown in the code), and fiddled with every setting possible in the SSRS Report builder as far as hiding parameters goes. The buyer and supplier are chosen from a drop down list. The error always happens when I finally execute the SetParameters method. If anyone has any ideas I greatly appreciate it.

```
Dim report As ServerReport = New ServerReport()
'(setting up url stuff)

'use a list for parameters
        Dim parameterList As New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)
        parameterList.Add(New ReportParameter("buyer", buyer, True))
        parameterList.Add(New ReportParameter("supplier", supplier, True))
        parameterList.Add(New ReportParameter("quoteDate", quoteDate.ToString, True))
        parameterList.Add(New ReportParameter("reqDate", reqDate.ToString, True))
        parameterList.Add(New ReportParameter("user", username, True))

        'use an array for parameters
        Dim params(4) As ReportParameter
        params(0) = New ReportParameter("buyer", buyer, False)
        params(1) = New ReportParameter("supplier", supplier, False)
        params(2) = New ReportParameter("quoteDate", quoteDate.ToString, False)
        params(3) = New ReportParameter("reqDate", reqDate.ToString, False)
        params(4) = New ReportParameter("user", username, False)

        report.SetParameters(params)
        report.Refresh()

        'for testing 
        Dim reportData As Byte() = report.Render("PDF")
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\....." & reportName & ".pdf", reportData)
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Could you post the stack trace?